# Sed | awk to remove line after matching next line

Tags: regex, linux, bash, awk, sed

if `Name` comes back to back then delete first name

```
Name john
Age 30

Name Alice

Name Travis
Age 12

Name Monty

Name Hannah
```

desired output

```
Name john
Age 30

Name Travis
Age 12

Name Hannah
```

Commands I tried:

```
sed '/^Name/ {N; /\n$/d}' file.txt

sed '/Name/{$!N;/\n\nName/!P;D}' file.txt
```

Comment: `sed '/^Name/ {N; /\n$/d}'` works as intended for me on `sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2`... what is your version?

Comment: GNU sed version 4.2.1

Comment: paste output of `sed '/^Name/ {N; /\n$/d}'` to question.. perhaps you have dos style line ending?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a method by using `awk`,

awk_script:

```
BEGIN{a=0}                                                                                                                                                                                                   
/Name/{ if(a==1){print $0;name=""}else{name=$0"\n"} a=1 }
/Age/{printf "%s%s\n\n",name,$0; a=0;}
```

Then execute:

```
$ awk -f awk_sc file.txt
Name john
Age 30

Name Travis
Age 12

Name Hannah
```

Brief explaination:

The variable `a` is the flag used to record if `Name` is shown up previously. Set `a=0` after the line has been printed

Answer (score 1):

You can use this awk command:

```
awk 'NF && /^Name/ {n=NR; p=$0; next}
     NF && n {if ($0 !~ /^Name/) print p; n=0} END{if (n) print p} 1' file

Name john
Age 30


Name Travis
Age 12


Name Hannah
```

Comment: It seems you would have spared blank line between two printed lines. :)

Comment: Yes that can be done. At present it just strips multiple `Name` lines

Answer (score 0):

May not be exactly what you are looking for, but why not try to keep only what you are interested in.

```
 sed -n '/^Name/ {N; /Age.*/p}' file.txt
```

Will give you following result

```
Name john
Age 30
Name Travis
Age 12
```